# Querying another database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question regarding querying from different DB.

So at the moment I am using,

```
DATABASE NAME = DATABASEA with 192.168.100.195
```

I am logged in with database A.

At the same time I wanna query something and get info from DATABASEB with IP 192.168.10.22 with different username and password

How do i implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a remote database connection in one of the databases.  Then a query into the database can also refer to parts of the remote database.

See the documentation for [`CREATE DATABASE LINK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm).

Comment: OK so i create a database link,

CREATE DATABASE LINK MARKETLINK
CONNECT TO USERNAME IDENTIFIED BY PWDUSERNAME
USING 'MARKETLINK'

and i cant query using select * from job@marketlink

Comment: @marmar:  What does "can't query" mean?  Is there an error?  Does it hang?

Comment: it takes forever... and throws an error that says error downloading resources XML file

Comment: @marmar - What is the exact Oracle error message?  Something starting with ORA-xxxxx or TNS-xxxxx I would expect.

Comment: Error downloading resources XML file : error downloading URL: http://community-downloads.quest.com/toadsoft/ORACLE/VERSION/online_resources.xml